# How to instal labview on raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi2, labview

A project am working on acquires LabView to be installed on raspberry pi 2 model B, and I am trying to find a solution but in vain, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now build and run LabVIEW applications on the Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 (and BeagleBone Black):

https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=blog:users:makerhub:2016-04-07-linx-3

You still need to develop the code in LabVIEW on Windows but you can use the Pi or BeagleBone as a deployment target.

My understanding is that this will work with any version of LabVIEW 2014 SP1, not just the Home/Student edition, **but** deployment to Pi or BeagleBone is only licensed for home or student use - for commercial use you'll still need to buy NI hardware, or an NI RT deployment license for a PC platform.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: You can not install LabVIEW on Raspberry pi 2 (EDIT: It is announced in the beginning of April 2016 that you can do so by this link: https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=blog:users:makerhub:2016-04-07-linx-3).

Because the Raspberry Pi uses a controller (ARM) with a different instruction set architecture than the one which supported by LabVIEW Real-Time, to work with NI LinuxRT targets.

There is some toolkit I never used, that compiles LabVIEW code to Raspberry pi stand-alone executable.
https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/

Comment: well yes, but it is coming soon , and I have one month for my project to be done, It is one that I cannot give up on, do you think you can tell me any way that I could compile labview script on a raspberry pi ? i need something that makes both work together somehow please..

Comment: You can write python code 0n Raspberry pi 2 and communicate Raspberry pi with LabVIEW trough TCP connection. It is the easy way.

Comment: What if the coding should only be pure labview? , what should I do?

Comment: You should give up the project. Or to simply tell your client why LabVIEW can't be directly run on Raspberry pi. There are many good descriptions on the web. Ex: https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-35053

Also, try to write these guys: https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/